# Plotting two datasets in one plotting area (graph)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colors

I have 2 dataframes (train_df and test_df). I want to plot them in one graph using plt.plot function.

Also want these datasets have different colors

Tried multiple methods but unsuccessfully. One example below:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt    
train_df.plot(figsize=(15,8), title="Sales", color='lime')
test_df.plot(figsize=(15,8), title="Sales", color='r')
```

I am getting 2 different plots instead of one

Much appreciate your help!

Comment: does this help? `ax = train_df.plot(figsize=(15,8), title="Sales", color='lime')
test_df.plot(ax=ax, figsize=(15,8), title="Sales", color='r')`

Comment: @Peyman - YES!! Thank you!!  One additional question - what if I need 3 plots instead for 2?

Comment: please consider marking it as answer :)

Comment: @Peyman - be happy to. How?

Comment: click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in green.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
ax = train_df.plot(figsize=(15,8), title="Sales", color='lime')
test_df.plot(ax=ax, figsize=(15,8), title="Sales", color='r')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
ax=plt.gca()
train_df.plot(figsize=(15,8), title="Sales", color='lime', ax=ax)
test_df.plot(figsize=(15,8), title="Sales", color='r',ax=ax)
plt.show()
```